# Passing include headers to g++

Tags: perl, g++

I am calling `g++` from a Perl script on a `hello world.cpp` file which includes a header from `path\include\ddk`.I am giving as parametres a list of include paths separated by `;`. The problem is that it takes it as a whole and I get the info : 
`ignoring nonexistent directory "D:\gnu\gcc-4.8.1\include\GL;D:\gnu\gcc-4.8.1\include\ddk"`

Same with `,` separated includes.

The system call is something like:
`g++ -v -c -fno-show-column #S\\\$> -o #B\\\$%\.o #opt`**`-I$i_incl`**

And `$i_incl` is actually : 
`D:\gnu\gcc-4.8.1\include\GL;D:\gnu\gcc-4.8.1\include\ddk`

What am I doing wrong?

This is a sample simplifyed version of the code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catfile);
my $compilerRoot = "D:\\gnu\\gcc-4.8.1";
my $i_incl =catfile($compilerRoot,"\\include\\GL;").catfile($compilerRoot,"\\include\\ddk");

$ENV{'PATH'} = "d:\\gnu\\gcc-4.8.1\\bin;". $ENV{'PATH'};
my $command = "g++ -v -c C:\\Users\\asdf\\Documents\\hello.cpp -fno-show-column -o hello -I$i_incl";
system($command);
```

And the `hello.cpp` has :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<glu.h> // this is the lib which i am trying to include from 
                  D:\gnu\gcc-4.8.1\include\GL 
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Hello World!";
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @Jens,Are you referring to the output string quotes? `ignoring nonexistent directory "D:\gnu\gcc-4.8.1\include\GL;D:\gnu\gcc-4.8.1\include\ddk"`

Comment: Those are compiler info quotes to isolate the string @Jens

Comment: Which os you are running?

Comment: @asdf, can you post the perl script? It seems to me like you need to split your arguments at `;`

Comment: @Jens, unless Linux has D:\ drive and \ directories... Windows it is ;)

Comment: @Gerry yes this is windows

Comment: can you kindly provide the full code?

Comment: @Jens That would be hard to add the whole script, but i will add a short variant of it

Comment: Please add as much as you can so I can see how you interpret the .cpp file

Comment: You would probably need to call `my @array =~ split /;/, $I_incl` but post the code and let me see first before posting answer

Comment: Thanks for the code. let me look through it quick.

Comment: @Gerry The difference with `@array` is that now in the command call shown in console i have the paths`-ID:\gnu\gcc-4.8.1\include\ddk D:\gnu\gcc-4.8.1\include\GL` with spaces and the compiler doesn't even look into that folder

Comment: Yes, that was before I saw the code :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126899/discussion-between-asdf-and-gerry).

Comment: @Gerry Am i limited to 1 path/ each `-I` used? e.g. `-Ipath1` `-Ipath2` etc . Unfortunately,I can't acces the chat discussion link due to proxy limitations

Comment: that is why  we need to create a loop in the perl script so that it does a single path each time. I am trying to duplicate the environment quick and my directories are different than yours, so let me go through this quick

Comment: @Gerry I found a work-arround finally by setting in the environment variable `CPATH` the string `$i_incl`

Comment: ah ok. So you are sorted out now?

Comment: @Gerry Yes. Also for the answer bellow I wouldn't use that because if I have 1000 files let's say and 20 include paths, I will end up in a very unefficient situation

Comment: Ok. glad you are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot duplicate the environment, too much to do, can you try this please?

```
my @i_incl = split /;/, =catfile($compilerRoot,"\\include\\GL;").catfile($compilerRoot,"\\include\\ddk");

$ENV{'PATH'} = "d:\\gnu\\gcc-4.8.1\\bin;". $ENV{'PATH'};
foreach $i_incl(@i_incl) {
my $command = "g++ -v -c C:\\Users\\asdf\\Documents\\hello.cpp -fno-show-column -o hello -I$i_incl";
system($command);
}
```